# Mongoose: Populate nested array of objectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I have a `User`model the schema is as below, I'm trying to populate the subcategories in the `deals` and the `wishes` but not able to.

```
image: { type: String, default: 'NA' },
firstName: { type: String, default: 'first name' },
lastName: { type: String, default: 'last name' },
email: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, trim: true },
password: { type: String, min: 6 },
deals: [
  {
    _id : false,
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    subCategory: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subcategory' }]
  }
],
wishes: [
  {
    _id : false,
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    subCategory: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subcategory' }]
  }
]
```

Here is a sample JSON response

```
"deals": [
  {
      "subCategory": [
          "5bc419cea25fc606153bdbe4",
          "5bc419cea25fc606153bdbe3"
      ],
      "category": "5bc419cea25fc606153bdbe2"
  }
],
"wishes": [
  {
      "subCategory": [
          "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe5",
          "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe7"
      ],
      "category": "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe5"
  }
]
```

I am able to populate the `deals.category` but not `deals.subcategory`

```
// method to get users with populated deals and wishes
allUsers: async (req, res, next) => {
  const users = await User.find({})
    .populate('deals.category', 'id name')
    .populate('wishes.category', 'id name')
    .populate('deals.subCategory');

  return respondSuccess(res, null, users);
},

// currently the response i'm getting
"deals": [
  {
      "subCategory": [],
      "category": {
          "_id": "5bc419cea25fc606153bdbe2",
          "name": "Auto"
      }
  }
],
"wishes": [
  {
      "subCategory": [
          "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe5",
          "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe7"
      ],
      "category": {
          "_id": "5bc41a40a25fc606153bdbe5",
          "name": "Baby Sitting"
      }
  }
]
```

looking for much-needed help.

thank you

Comment: Don't you think your `Schema` design will fail and populate query also when you will have more than one deals in array ?

Comment: @Aabid thank you for your response, The this design is because the category and subcategory may change at any point of time, thought of embedding because of the changeable category or subcategory i had to reference.  The `deals.category` is working fine but not the `subcategory`

Comment: @Aabid please do provide me your approach of the scheme. or just a reference of ideal solution. thank you..